# How to avoid comparing version number with a string in Python?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, comparison

I am trying to find the latest version of a product from an XML page. The element "component-version" in the xml is the version number in most cases, but in one case it is the string "Current Version," and I get a error when I compare using LooseVersion with the other versions (eg. 1.12.1, 1.11.0). I am wondering if there is a way around this error. Thanks in advance!

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET    
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

product = 'Product Name'

def get_latest_version(product):

    r = requests.get("http://samplexmlwebsite.com")
    variable = r.content.decode("utf-8") #Turned from a byte type to a variable
    root = ET.fromstring(variable)
    version_number =""
    for item in root.findall('item'):
        name = item.find('component-name').text
        version = item.find('component-version').text
        if name == product:
           if not version_number:
              version_number = version
           elif LooseVersion(version_number) < LooseVersion(version):
              version_number = version                  


    print(version_number)
    return version_number

get_latest_version(product)
```

Comment: Maybe use `regex` to determine if it says "current version" or "component-version"?

Comment: So, what would be the expected behavior if you get 'Current Version'? Try to code that.

Comment: Isn't `Current Version" the latest version as well? I.e. just add extra if clause and if matched, that's it... and yeah, I'd compare that one as a string. ;)

Comment: I think that problem is that when I do elif LooseVersion("current version") < LooseVersion(1.12.0) it results in an error. I hope to only find and print/return the actual versions in their number form

Comment: But if "current version" is latest... you can have one more `elif version_number == "current version: pass" before the `LooseVersion` comparison. If it's already greater then `version` by definition.

Comment: Right, but what about the case of "older version" rather than "current version"? I hope to find a way to not compare the words with the number and only return the values with the numbers.

Comment: Use `try/except` to handle the problematic cases.